# How can I check whether or not pop-ups are allowed to show in client's browser?

Tags: javascript, popup

As response to some actions I'm showing a popup to user, and I want to be able to notify the user that (s)he will not see the information which (s)he is asking for if (s)he has forbidden popups on this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like following

```
var windowName = 'userConsole'; 
var popUp = window.open('/popup-page.php', windowName, 'width=1000, height=700, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable');
if (popUp == null || typeof(popUp)=='undefined') {  
    alert('Please disable your pop-up blocker and click the "Open" link again.'); 
} 
else {  
    popUp.focus();
}
```

[Taken from this link. not tested](https://davidwalsh.name/popup-block-javascript)